# gradient shaded confidence interval

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I want to improvise my regression plot shade which is proportional to density. For example is the confidence interval is narrow the shade is dense while if confidence interval wide the fill color is light. The result graph might look like this:

[image]

Here is an working example:

```
set.seed(1234)
md <- c(seq(0.01, 1, 0.01), rev(seq(0.01, 1, 0.01)))
cv <-  c(rev(seq(0.01, 1, 0.01)), seq(0.01, 1, 0.01))
rv <- rnorm (length(md), 0.1, 0.05)

 df <- data.frame(x =1:length(md),  F = md*2.5 + rv, L =md*2.5 -rv-cv, U =md*2.5+ rv+ cv)
 plot(df$x, df$F, ylim = c(0,4), type = "l")

 polygon(c(df$x,rev(df$x)),c(df$L,rev(df$U)),col = "cadetblue", border = FALSE)
 lines(df$x, df$F, lwd = 2)
 #add red lines on borders of polygon
 lines(df$x, df$U, col="red",lty=2)
 lines(df$x, df$L, col="red",lty=2)
```

Comment: thanks, where is source code for vwReg function, I could not find it ...

Comment: Here is a solution (last example) using base graphics system [www.alisonsinclair.ca](http://www.alisonsinclair.ca/2011/03/shading-between-curves-in-r/) that can be adapted to your data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `densregion()` command in the `denstrip` package seems to do what you want. A little adaptation from the example in its help page:

```
require(denstrip)
x <- 1:10
nx <- length(x)
est <- seq(0, 1, length=nx)^3
se <- seq(.7,1.3,length.out=nx)/qnorm(0.975)
y <- seq(-3, 3, length=100)
z <- matrix(nrow=nx, ncol=length(y))
for(i in 1:nx) z[i,] <- dnorm(y, est[i], se[i])
plot(x, type="n", ylim=c(-3, 3),xlab="")
densregion(x, y, z)
lines(x,est,col="white")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for nice answer,  it gives two different direction of gradiants i.e. the toward the line of fit is more darker as well as width of the confidence interval itself.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That is because the standard deviation increases for increasing $x$; therefore the peak of the normal density is lower (e.g., `dnorm(0,0,1)` $>$ `dnorm(0,0,2)`). If you want the greyscale to be the same around the regression line, you can rescale the `z` matrix (but then the greyscale will not correspond to the "real" density, only to a scaled multiple of the density).